# Newtonsoft DeserializeXNode expands internal arrays incorrectly

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xml, json.net

I have a JSON object like the following:

```
{
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2",
  "property3": ["value3","value4","value5"]
}
```

When I try to use DeserializeXNode to convert to XML, though, the array goes away.

```
<MyObj>
    <property1>value1</property1>
    <property2>value2</property2>
    <property3>value3</property3>
    <property3>value4</property3>
    <property3>value5</property3>
</MyObj>
```

This causes issue when I try to re-serialize back to the object, because I get a "cannot convert string to string[]" error. Moreover, when I try to parse the document, the duplicate properties are overwritten and only the last value remains. I've tried setting the third parameter of DeserializeXNode to true thinking that would mark the array properly, but that doesn't change anything.

By my understanding from the Newtonsoft docs, the XML should look more like:

```
<MyObj>
    <property1>value1</property1>
    <property2>value2</property2>
    <property3 type="array">
        <item>value3</item>
        <item>value4</item>
        <item>value5</item>
    </property3>
</MyObj>
```

What do I need to do to get the array to properly translate into the XML so that it will come back to JSON as an array?

For reference, here is the code I'm using (inherited, so I'm not sure if it makes sense):

ObjectToXML:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
var xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "MyObj", true);
return xdoc.ToString();
```

XMLToObject:

```
XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.None);
d.Descendants().ForEach(e => e.Attributes().Remove());
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(d);
json = json.Replace("\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-16\"},\"MyObj\":{", "")
    .Replace("{\"MyObj\":", "")
    .Replace("}}", "}")
    .Replace("{\"anyType\":", "")
    .Replace("]}", "]");
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

And the object itself:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
    public string[] property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What *should* the xml look like?

Comment: @AakashM Edited with what I expected to see based on the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you've read this in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm). I've looked and I can't find anything that suggests the XML should look as you've suggested.

How this works is that multiple elements with the same name can be inferred to be an array.  From the docs:

> Multiple nodes with the same name at the same level are grouped together into an array.

And if there is only one element that originated from an array, then there is an overload you're using that instructs the serialiser to add an attribute indicating that element is an array. Your output would look something like this:

```
<MyObj xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <property1>value1</property1>
  <property2>value2</property2>
  <property3 json:Array="true">value3</property3>
</MyObj>
```

And if you round trip it via XML using this code:

```
var asXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "MyObj", writeArrayAttribute: true);
var asJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(asXml, Formatting.Indented, omitRootObject: true);
```

You get exactly the same JSON back. So I can't find a problem here.

You can see the results in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tyt8db), including deserialising to `MyObj`.

Comment: Yes, if I could get the XML to convert back into the JSON like that, it would fall back into the object perfectly. That's not happening. The XML only contains the last value in the array and without the array attribute.

Comment: @Roger I've updated my answer. Your JSON round trips via XML exactly in my tests.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I replaced my methods with your code, and it seems to be working for multiple values just fine. However, single value arrays break on the deserialize because the JSON returns "property3": [{"#text": "value3"}] for some reason. This happens in your fiddle as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @Roger now that *is* strange. I expect it's becuase the XML has attribtues and that's how the serialiser handles elements with attributes: the attributes are key/value pairs and the text with the key `#text`. It sounds like what you really ought to be using is `XmlSerializer` here - that would get you from your XML to `MyObj` without the JSON step. If you need the JSON you could then serialise the object. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/544CIX) which shows this working with a single item in the array.