# Deserialize Json to XML with array of objects contained in single XML node

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net, deserialization

I need to generate XMLDocument from JObjects, and I'm trying to figure out how to make an array of JObjects convert properly to XML. This is the section giving me trouble:

```
JObject billsegment = new JObject
    {
        {"ext_bill_id", bill.ExternalBillID},
        {"cust", new JObject
            {
                {"typ_id_cust","1"},
                {"id_cust", bill.CustomerID}
            }
        },
        // This element is giving me trouble
        {"bill_line_list", GetBillLines(bill.LineData)}
    };
```

**The problem:** The resulting XML is:

```
<bill_line_list>
    <bill_line>
        <line_no>1</line_no>
        <id_elm_bill>06159</id_elm_bill>
    </bill_line>    
</bill_line_list>
<bill_line_list>
    <bill_line>
        <line_no>2</line_no>
        <id_elm_bill>05432</id_elm_bill>
    </bill_line>    
</bill_line_list>
```

Notice there are two `<bill_line_list>` elements, of which I only want one. I want the result to be:

```
<bill_line_list>
    <bill_line>
        <line_no>1</line_no>
        <id_elm_bill>06159</id_elm_bill>
    </bill_line>    
    <bill_line>
        <line_no>2</line_no>
        <id_elm_bill>05432</id_elm_bill>
    </bill_line>    
</bill_line_list>
```

My `GetBillLines()` method returns a JArray, which I formulate like this:

```
JArray GetBillLines(dynamic lineData)
{
    int num_lines = lineData.NumLines;
    JArray lines = new JArray();

    for (int lineNum = 1; lineNum < num_lines+1; lineNum++)
        {
            JObject line = new JObject
                {
                    {"line_no", lineNum },
                    {"id_elm_bill", billData.Lines[lineNum].billCode},
                };
            lines.Add(new JObject
                {
                    {"bill_line", line}
                });
        }
    return lines;
}
```

**What I've tried:** I've tried making the return type of my `GetBillLines()` to JArray and JToken[], and I've tried returning the JArray with `.ToArray()`. Also, in my `JObject billsegment` I've tried changing the last line to

```
JToken.FromObject(GetBillLines(bill.LineData))
```

and other various things. I'm wondering why it creates two `<bill_line_list>`s, since when I create the object I am only adding ONE bill_line_list property, and setting the JToken as an array.

I know that you can force Json arrays when serializing from XML (via `json:Array='true'`), is there an equivalent the other way around?

Comment: If you're calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode()` to convert to XML, [this answer may shed some light](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638264/424129): It looks like somebody at Newtonsoft got drunk at lunch and decided that when converting from XML to JSON, successive XML elements with the same name should be converted into a JSON array. Once they'd done something as crazy as that, the only way to proceed was to go twice as crazy and assume that all arrays in JSON should be converted to a series of like-named elements in XML. That answer mentions a `writeArrayAttribute` parameter, which...

Comment: ...does exist, but has no effect on the generated XML when I use it. I suppose, technically, this isn't a "bug", because it's deliberate. If there's a halfway sane justification, I'd like to hear it. The fault, anyhow, is not in your JSON: It is in the converter. There's no way to say "array" loud enough for that thing to listen. I'd write my own and report this as a bug.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this info. I can probably manipulate my XMLDocument once it's been generated and deal with the multiple `<bill_line_list>` elements, but if possible I would like to avoid doing that and just deserialize it correctly from the start.

Comment: I agree. But I don’t think it’s possible. Maybe somebody at Newtonsoft would have a suggestion.

Comment: You might convert to C# classes instead of JSON, and serialize with conventional .NET XML serialization.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, how would you handle multiple elements with the same name if not as an array?

Comment: I would handle them as an array. I thought the problem was that Newtonsoft’s serislizer wouldn’t give you one.